# Problem writing 0xFF to file

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a 0xFF to file in java using PrintStream. Other values are written to the file correctly when I open it with a Hex editor but the value that is suppose to show 0xFF got 0xC3BF instead.

The variable type used is int. After a few tried I also discover that the "maximum" value i can put is 0x7F this will be displayed correctly in the Hex editor, if i put 0x80 then the hex editor will display 0xC280.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little investigation shows that the outputted values are UTF-8 encoded (the following lines are Python):

```
In [1]: "\xc2\x80".decode("utf-8")
Out[1]: u'\x80'

In [2]: "\xc3\xbf".decode("utf-8")
Out[2]: u'\xff'
```

Make sure you choose the correct overload for `print`/`println`/`write` in order to write the integer value as a byte instead of as character or string. See the [documentation of PrintStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for all overloads.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction! I change from .print to .write and it works.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong is that you're writing characters, and they're being encoded as UTF-8. Write bytes instead.