# Java String UTF-8 decodes 0xFF as 0xC3BF

Tags: java, string, utf-8, byte

I've got an odd problem with writing certain bytes to a file with OutputStream.

The problem seems to be caused by "encoding" of the data.

If I explicity write to the outputstream

```
saveFile.write(new byte[]{(byte)0xFF});
```

It works correctly and I see 0xFF in my hex editor.

But when I try and do this with strings it doesn't work. Example:

```
scriptData = "some script data thats all text and stuff" + ((char)0xFF) + ((char)0x3B);
saveFile.write(scriptData.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

In my hex editor I see the text and then 0xC3BF and then 0x3B. Why does the 0x3B write correctly to the file but the 0xFF change to 0xC3BF?

There was one other thread I saw about this but it was involving PrintStream which I'm not using AFAIK.

[Problem writing 0xFF to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908259/problem-writing-0xff-to-file)

Thanks.

Comment: This is an encoding problem.  Code point 0xFF must be UTF-8 encoded, and 0xC3BF is the UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for the UTF-8 equivalent of the character 0xFF (quite explicitly). The character 0xFF, in UTF-8, is expressed as two bytes: 0xC3 and 0xBF. If you don't want UTF-8 encoding, don't use `getBytes` with UTF-8 encoding.

Remember that UTF-8 is not a single-byte-per-character encoding. UTF-8 (like all of the Unicode transformations) is required to be able to represent every Unicode character. That means that some characters, in UTF-8, are one byte long; others are two bytes long; still others are three bytes long, and still others are four bytes long.

Comment: Oh.. I feel dumb. I just removed the encoding param and it worked. Thanks.