# Processing PrintWriter not working correctly

Tags: java, processing, printwriter

I have been really confused on this, and I've been trying to solve it for about the past 4 hours. But now I give up. I am trying to write bytes to a file. Let's call it test.bin. If I use my Printwriter and do

```
pw.write(0xff);
```

or

```
pw.write((char)0xff);
```

or

```
pw.write((byte)0xff);
```

And I look at the file in a hex editor, None of them actually write 0xFF. They write 0xC3BF. If I do `pw.write(0x00);` then it actually writes 0x00. I assume this is because it is signed? If so, how do I get around this? All I want to do is write 0xFF to a file :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem writing 0xFF to file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908259/problem-writing-0xff-to-file)

Comment: You are writing in UTF8 encoding. 0xFF in UTF8 is 0xC3BF. Use Outputstream instead of Printwriter and itll work

Comment: Ill put that in answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing in UTF8 encoding. 0xFF in UTF8 is 0xC3BF. Use Outputstream instead of Printwriter and itll work